# Replacing and combining elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to increase the level of nesting in the following list while adding a 'tag' to each leaf:

```
testd = {{59.15, 13.2, 13.52, 0.7}, {77.21, 12.27, 0.12, 0.01}, 
         {77.25, 12.35, 1.01, 0.02}, {78.22, 11.74, 1.26, 0.01}, 
         {79.26, 11.37, 1.03, 0.02}};

   tag = {a, b, c, d}
```

So, the end product would look like

```
 (*    {{{a, 59.15},{b, 13.2},{c, 13.52},{d, 0.7}},
        {{a, 77.21},{b, 12.27},{c, 0.12},{d, 0.01}}, 
         << ... >>
        {{a, 79.26},{b, 11.37},{c, 1.03},{d, 0.02}}}  *)
```

I can use

```
Replace[testd, x_ -> {x}, {2}]
```

to get

```
(* {{{59.15},{13.2},{13.52},{0.7}},{{77.21},{12.27},{0.12},{<0.01}},
   {{77.25},{12.35},{1.01},{0.02}},{{78.22},{11.74},{1.26},{0.01}},
   {{79.26},{11.37},{1.03},{0.02}}}  *)
```

I have tried

```
Replace[testd, x_ -> {#, x}, {2}] & /@ tag
```

> {{{{a, b, c, d}, 59.15}, {{a, b, c, d}, 13.2}, {{a, b, c, d}, 
>      13.52}, {{a, b, c, d}, 0.7}}, {{{a, b, c, d}, 
>      77.21}, {{a, b, c, d}, 12.27}, {{a, b, c, d}, 0.12}, {{a, b, c, d},
>       "<0.01"}}, {{{a, b, c, d}, 77.25}, {{a, b, c, d}, 
>      12.35}, {{a, b, c, d}, 1.01}, {{a, b, c, d}, 
>      0.02}}, {{{a, b, c, d}, 78.22}, {{a, b, c, d}, 
>      11.74}, {{a, b, c, d}, 1.26}, {{a, b, c, d}, 
>      0.01}}, {{{a, b, c, d}, 79.26}, {{a, b, c, d}, 
>      11.37}, {{a, b, c, d}, 1.03}, {{a, b, c, d}, 0.02}}}

which is not what i want...

Can someone help me with the right syntax? or suggest a better way?

Comment: I'm happy for this question to be removed (if necessary). @rm -rf might feel behooven to add his `Riffle` solution to the other question..?

Comment: The `Riffle` solution is nice, on the other hand rm-rf uses `Map` everywhere. I'm sure my `Inner` solution is the most efficient.